Loop infinito en React
Hace poco terminé un proyecto de React, donde me encontré con un problema al momento de hacer peticiones utilizando useEffect.
El problema, a grandes rasgos, es que una dependencia del useEffect me genera un loop infinito, pero sin ella, no logro que mi proyecto sea dinámico, es decir, en ocaciones debo recargar la página para mostrar cambios.
Dejo un ejemplo de código, la dependencia 'usuario.listaReservas' es la que me provoca el loop infinito.
const [usuario, setUsuario] = useState([]);
const { decodedToken } = useJwt(authToken);
const usuarioId = decodedToken?.user?._id;

const fetchUsuario = async () => {
  try {
    if (authToken && usuarioId) {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `http://127.0.0.1:3000/user/${usuarioId}`,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: authToken,
          },
        }
      );
      setUsuario(response.data);
    } else {
      console.error("Token o usuario ID no disponibles");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error al obtener usuario:", error);
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  if (authToken && usuarioId) {
    fetchUsuario();
  }
}, [authToken, usuarioId, usuario.listaReservas]);


por el await antes del fetchUsuario() dentro del useEffect y verifica las dependencias del use efect porque a simple ojo solo deberia depender de usuario

Elimina la dependencia usuario.listaReservas. No la necesitas para ejecutar el método fetchUsuario. Si tienes problemas para mostrar los últimos resultados de listaReservas en el UI, revisa en todos lados donde estes haciendo una actualización del estado con setUsuario
Recuerda que cada actualización al estado es asíncrona, y si por alguna razón mandas llamar varias veces setUsuario al mismo tiempo, el resultado no va a ser el esperado.
